The operators for my derived class do not work as intended
I made this code that has 4 classes. The SpecialCharacter class has 2 bases, Hero and Enemy, both of which have Person as their base class.
#include <iostream>

class Person {
private:
    char* name;
    int level;
public:
    Person() {
        name = nullptr;
        level = 0;
    }

    Person(char* name, int level) {
        this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        this->level = level;
    }

    Person(const Person& p) {
        name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, p.name);
        level = p.level;
    }

    virtual ~Person() {
        delete[] name;
    }

    Person& operator=(const Person& p) {
        if (this != &p) {
            delete[] name;

            name = new char[strlen(p.name) + 1];
            strcpy(name, p.name);

            level = p.level;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const Person& p) const {
        return strcmp(this->name, p.name) < 0;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& p) {
        char nameTemp[100];
        is >> nameTemp >> p.level;

        delete[] p.name;
        p.name = new char[strlen(nameTemp) + 1];
        strcpy(p.name, nameTemp);

        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
        os << "name " << p.name << "\n";
        os << "level " << p.level << "\n";

        return os;
    }
};

class Hero : virtual public Person {
private:
    char* ability;
public:
    Hero() : Person() {
        ability = nullptr;
    }

    Hero(char* name, int level, char* ability) : Person(name, level) {
        this->ability = new char[strlen(ability) + 1];
        strcpy(this->ability, ability);
    }

    Hero(const Hero& h) : Person(h) {
        this->ability = new char[strlen(h.ability) + 1];
        strcpy(this->ability, h.ability);
    }

    virtual ~Hero() {
        delete[] ability;
    }

    Hero& operator=(const Hero& h) {
        if (this != &h) {
            Person::operator=(h);
            delete[] ability;
            this->ability = new char[strlen(h.ability) + 1];
            strcpy(this->ability, h.ability);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Hero& h) {
        is >> static_cast<Person&>(h);

        char tempAbil[100];
        is >> tempAbil;

        delete[] h.ability;
        h.ability = new char[strlen(tempAbil) + 1];
        strcpy(h.ability, tempAbil);

        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Hero& h) {
        os << static_cast<const Person&>(h);

        os << "ability " << h.ability << "\n";

        return os;
    }
};

class Enemy : virtual public Person {
protected:
    char* type;
public:
    Enemy() : Person() {
        type = nullptr;
    }

    Enemy(char* name, int level, char* type) : Person(name, level) {
        this->type = new char[strlen(type) + 1];
        strcpy(this->type, type);
    }

    Enemy(const Enemy& e) : Person(e) {
        this->type = new char[strlen(e.type) + 1];
        strcpy(this->type, e.type);
    }

    Enemy& operator=(const Enemy& e) {
        if (this != &e) {
            Person::operator=(e);
            delete[] type;
            type = new char[strlen(e.type) + 1];
            strcpy(type, e.type);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Enemy() {
        delete[] type;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Enemy& e) {
        is >> static_cast<Person&>(e);

        char temptype[100];
        is >> temptype;

        e.type = new char[strlen(temptype) + 1];
        strcpy(e.type, temptype);

        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Enemy& e) {
        os << static_cast<const Person&>(e);

        os << "type " << e.type << "\n";

        return os;
    }
};

class SpecialCharacter : public Hero, public Enemy {
private:
    int team;
public:
    SpecialCharacter() : Person(), Hero(), Enemy() {
        team = 0;
    }

    SpecialCharacter(char* name, int level, char* ability, char* type, int team) : Person(name, level), Hero(name, level, ability), Enemy(name, level, type) {
        this->team = team;
    }

    SpecialCharacter(const SpecialCharacter& sp) : Person(sp), Hero(sp), Enemy(sp) {
        this->team = sp.team;
    }

    SpecialCharacter& operator=(const SpecialCharacter& sp) {
        if (this != &sp) {
            Hero::operator=(sp);
            this->type = sp.type;
            this->team = sp.team;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SpecialCharacter& sp) {
        is >> static_cast<Hero&>(sp);
        char temptype[100];
        is >> temptype;

        sp.type = new char[strlen(temptype) + 1];
        strcpy(sp.type, temptype);
        is >> sp.team;

        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SpecialCharacter& sp) {
        os << static_cast<const Hero&>(sp);
        os << "type " << sp.type << "\n";

        os << "team number " << sp.team << "\n";

        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person** pers = new Person * [5];
    int i = 0, r;

    while (i < 5) {
        r = rand() % 3;

        if (r == 0) {
            std::cout << "Enter info for hero\n";
            Hero* e = new Hero();
            std::cin >> *e;
            pers[i] = e;
        }
        else if (r == 1) {
            std::cout << "Enter info for enemy\n";
            Enemy* in = new Enemy();
            std::cin >> *in;
            pers[i] = in;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Enter info for special character\n";
            SpecialCharacter* ps = new SpecialCharacter();
            std::cin >> *ps;
            pers[i] = ps;
        }

        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        Hero* e = dynamic_cast<Hero*>(pers[j]);
        if (e != nullptr) {
            std::cout << *e;
            continue;
        }

        Enemy* in = dynamic_cast<Enemy*>(pers[j]);
        if (in != nullptr) {
            std::cout << *in;
            continue;
        }

        SpecialCharacter* ps = dynamic_cast<SpecialCharacter*>(pers[j]);
        if (ps != nullptr) {
            std::cout << *ps;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

I tried to overload the << and >> operators for SpecialCharacter by using static_cast, which makes it so that it first reads/prints out the objects as a Hero type, after which it reads/prints out the member values of the Enemy
and the SpecialCharacter.
However, when I tested this code out in main(), it only displays the name, level and abilities for the SpecialCharacter objects, AKA the members from the Person and Hero classes.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Is it because of how I used dynamic_cast in the for loop from main()? Or have I overloaded the operators for SpecialCharacter incorrectly?

Switch to std::string for text.  Use std::string::c_str() in order to convert to char *, only as required.

In Person don't manage that memory manually. std::string would make the code much simpler.

If you use a different Coding Standard, where member names are different than parameter names, you can eliminate all the this-> syntax.  Extra typing increase the chance of injected issues.

FYI, C++ is different than other languages:  you don't need to allocate objects in dynamic memory in order to use them.  Treat objects like integers:  Just declare them and use them.  Prefer to stay far away from dynamic memory allocations; use sparingly and only when necessary.

Side notes: Use base-member initialization lists in your constructors. They are more efficient than the assignments you are using. As a bonus, they allow you to omit this->. Agree with @Thomas Matthews regarding std::string. Is there a reason you are not using it?

You can remove SpecialCharacter class.  Refactor the team member into the Person class.  Assign it a "not on a team" value.  Removing the SpecialCharacter class also removes the pain of multiple inheritance.

FYI: Using std::string reduces the amount of code you wrote to almost half the size.

If you are not allowed to use std::string, ie due to project restrictions, then you should write your own string class to eliminate all this unnecessary duplicate code.

SpecialCharacter derives from Hero. In your printing loop, your 1st dynamic_cast check for Hero* will succeed for SpecialCharacter objects, and then you continue to the next iteration, so you never get a chance to print out those objects' type and team  members.
Your printing loop should be checking for SpecialCharacter* first instead of last.
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

    // DO THIS HERE!
    SpecialCharacter* ps = dynamic_cast<SpecialCharacter*>(pers[j]);
    if (ps != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *ps;
        continue;
    }

    Hero* e = dynamic_cast<Hero*>(pers[j]);
    if (e != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *e;
        continue;
    }

    Enemy* in = dynamic_cast<Enemy*>(pers[j]);
    if (in != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *in;
        continue;
    }

    /* NOT HERE !
    SpecialCharacter* ps = dynamic_cast<SpecialCharacter*>(pers[j]);
    if (ps != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *ps;
        continue;
    }
    */
}


@Remy Lebeau correctly identified the cause of the specific issue the OP asked about, and so earned my up-vote. Be sure to read his answer.
There is, however, a larger problem here. The OP has a virtual hierarchy, which is never used. Although there are plenty of upcasts and downcasts, there are no virtual functions in any of the code in the OP. All of the casting can be avoided by the proper use of virtual methods.
In particular, a virtual put function will solve the issue posed in the original question. In each class, friend function operator<< should call the virtual put method, and let the vtable sort out which put function is invoked.
The mistake in the OP is not that the downcasts were checked in the wrong order (although they were). The mistake is that downcasts had to be used in the first place.
class Person {

    //...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Person& p) {
        p.put(ost);
        return ost;
    }
protected:
    virtual void put(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost << "name " << name 
            << "\nlevel " << level 
            << '\n';
    }
};

class Hero : virtual public Person {

    //...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Hero& h) {
        h.put(ost);
        return ost;
    }
protected:
    void put(std::ostream& ost) const override {
        Person::put(ost);
        ost << "ability " << ability << '\n';
    }
};

class Enemy : virtual public Person {

    //...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Enemy& e) {
        e.put(ost);
        return ost;
    }
protected:
    void put(std::ostream& ost) const override {
        Person::put(ost);
        ost << "type " << type << '\n';
    }
};

class SpecialCharacter : public Hero, public Enemy {

    //...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const SpecialCharacter& sp) {
        sp.put(ost);
        return ost;
    }
protected:
    void put(std::ostream& ost) const override {
        Hero::put(ost);
        ost << "type " << type 
            << "\nteam number " << team 
            << '\n';
    }
};

Output from a sample run
With these changes, the order in which you check the downcasts does not matter. This run was made using the uncorrected version of function main, from the OP.
// from function `main` in the OP:
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    Hero* e = dynamic_cast<Hero*>(pers[j]);     // <---------- Order does not matter
    if (e != nullptr) {
        std::cout 
            << typeid(*pers[j]).name() << '\n'  // <---------- Operator `typeid`
            << *e << '\n';
        continue;
    }

    Enemy* in = dynamic_cast<Enemy*>(pers[j]);
    if (in != nullptr) {
        std::cout
            << typeid(*pers[j]).name() << '\n'
            << *in << '\n';
        continue;
    }

    SpecialCharacter* ps = dynamic_cast<SpecialCharacter*>(pers[j]);
    if (ps != nullptr) {
        std::cout
            << typeid(*pers[j]).name() << '\n'
            << *ps << '\n';
        continue;
    }
}

The only significant modification to function main was to call typeid(*pers[j]).name(), so that class name is displayed in the output.
Output
Each class was printed with the correct set of member variables. Thus, the correct put method was called for each one.
Enter info for special character
sp1 1 sp1 sp1 1

Enter info for hero
h1 1 h1

Enter info for hero
h2 2 h2

Enter info for special character
sp2 2 sp2 sp2 2

Enter info for enemy
e1 1 e1

class SpecialCharacter
name sp1
level 1
ability sp1
type sp1
team number 1

class Hero
name h1
level 1
ability h1

class Hero
name h2
level 2
ability h2

class SpecialCharacter
name sp2
level 2
ability sp2
type sp2
team number 2

class Enemy
name e1
level 1
type e1

Get rid of the downcasts
Of course, the whole point was to avoid using any downcasts at all.
The foregoing loop can now be replaced by this:
// Corrected loop from function `main`:
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    std::cout
        << typeid(*pers[j]).name() << '\n'
        << *pers[j] << '\n';
}

Side notes
The OP deserves credit for writing true "Rule of Three" classes. But then, in function main, he calls new and new[] without any corresponding calls to delete and delete[]. It's a bit of a nitpick, because the operating system will reclaim the leaked memory as soon as the program ends, but I would prefer to see std::vector used in function main, perhaps with std::unique_ptr to manage the pointers.
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>> pers;

Also, when you are forbidden to use std::string, the recommendation, by Remy Lebeau, to write your own String class is a good one. That would push the RAII stuff into class String, and thereby simplify the rest of the code.
